# Get the intersections of a list and list of Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection

two list

```
ListOne = ['steve','rob','jym','rich','bell','mick']
ListTwo = [('steve',22 ,178), ('rob', 23 ,189), ('jym', 25,165), ('steven',18 ,187), ('Manro',16 ,200), ('bell',21 ,167), ('mick', 24 ,180)]
```

How can i get the just the data from ListTwo for the students on the ListOne something like `two list intersections`.

Output like :

```
ListTwo = [('steve',22 ,178), ('rob', 23 ,189), ('jym', 25,165), ('bell',21 ,167), ('mick', 24 ,180)]
```

I tried this, but I'm looking for something more officiant:

```
for row in ListTwo:   
    if row[0] in ListOne :
        print 'this student exist' + `row[0]`

    else :
        for i,e in enumerate(ListTwo):
        #Check the student with the above results, will be removed
            if row[0] == e: 
                temp=list(ListTwo[i])
                pprint.pprint('I will remove this student : ' + `e`)
                #Remove the Student
                for f, tmp in enumerate(temp):
                     temp[f]= []
                #pprint.pprint(temp)
                ListTwo[i]=tuple(temp)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[rec for rec in ListTwo if rec[0] in ListOne]
```

To make it faster, you can replace list-lookups with set-lookups, by first converting the list to a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
ListOne = set(ListOne)
```

Comment: teve is which leads me to believe its a typo

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah must be a typo, when I first saw his code I assumed he ran it and it gave that output but after running it I know it does not

Comment: @jamylak that's why your comment should be about the question... OP's code doesn't generate the output he wanted because of the typo.

Comment: Works like a charm could you please explain more about the set command, and how will make the search faster, a link will be very helpful for the next person who has the same question. Thank you very much @shx2 !!!

Comment: @mongotop no sweat, added links to my answer.

Comment: @shx2 Even with the typo fixed OP's code doesn't generate the output he stated in the question, anyway it's no big deal it seems to be solved now

Answer (score 2):

one way is numpy

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array(list2)
print a[numpy.in1d(a[:,0],list1)]
```

but I would probably do a list comprehension as advised by shx2 ... numpy will change your types

this would take column 0 of your  2d numpy array (which is the names of the tuples)

`numpy.in1d` would create a mask `[True,False,etc]` based on if the name is in the other list

then it  takes the original array and uses boolean indexing

```
>>> a = numpy.array(ListTwo)
>>> a[numpy.in1d(a[:,0],ListOne)]
array([['steve', '22', '178'],
       ['rob', '23', '189'],
       ['jym', '25', '165'],
       ['bell', '21', '167'],
       ['mick', '24', '180']],
      dtype='|S6')
>>>
```

Comment: I got this error : `>>> print a[a[:,0].in1d(ListOne)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'in1d'
` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lor for the quick reply!! I got this new arror : `>>> print a[numpy.in1d(a[:,0],ListOne)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'in1d'
`

Comment: what version of numpy are you using? ...editted to show my output